# Setting keys in appsettings.json with ENV variables - ASP.NET Core 3.1 Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, environment-variables

I have a .NET Core Web API and I am trying to find out how to use ENV variables to configure keys in my `appsetttings.json` so I can then populate with data when creating a Docker container.

So far I have managed to inject `IOptions<>` into my test controller and I was able to debug the values, which were NULL because the app is currently not running in a container just yet.

Test controller:

```
namespace TestWebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IOptions<EnvironmentConfiguration> _environmentConfiguration;

        public TestController(IOptions<EnvironmentConfiguration> environmentConfiguration)
        {
            _environmentConfiguration = environmentConfiguration;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("testmessage")]
        public ActionResult<string> TestMessage()
        {
            var test = _environmentConfiguration.Value;

            return Ok($"Value from EXAMPLE_1 is {test.EXAMPLE_1}");
        }
    }
}
```

Environment configuration:

```
namespace TestWebApplication.Models
{
    public class EnvironmentConfiguration
    {
        public string EXAMPLE_1 { get; set; }
        public string EXAMPLE_2 { get; set; }
     }
}
```

After following some older tutorials I noticed I actually never needed to put any code in `ConfigureServices` for this to work.

For example, lets say I have this part of my `appsettings.json`:

```
"eureka": {
    "client": {
      ......
    },
    "instance": {
      "port": "xxxx",
      "ipAddress": "SET THIS WITH ENV",
    }
  }
```

How could I set an environment variable to populate the `ipAddress` so when I go to Docker, I run something like this:

> docker run .... -e EXAMPLE_1 -e IP_ADDRESS ....

Comment: You might need to add `configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables()` in your application startup, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.environmentvariablesextensions.addenvironmentvariables?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't store them in environment-specific appsettings files? I believe it's fairly standard to have, for example, appsettings.development.json and appsettings.production.json. https://www.jerriepelser.com/tutorials/airport-explorer/basic/working-with-configuration/

Comment: @SamWalpole it's common practice to use environment variables too, that's why `AddEnvironmentVariables()` is added by default by the host builder, and *overrides* the values set by the settings files. In container environments configuration is passed as env variables from the host to the containers.

Comment: @SamWalpole a settings file can only change during deployment. An orchestrator though can change settings at runtime and possibly restart containers as needed to get them to run with the new settings, eg all at once, in waves etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For instance you have a section in `appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "Section1" : {
        "SectionA": {
            "PropA": "A",
            "PropB": "B"
        }
    }
}
```

and a class:

```
public class SectionA
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}
```

In `Startup.cs` map class to section to be able to inject `IOptions<SectionA>`:

```
services.Configure<SectionA>(Configuration.GetSection("Section1:SectionA"));
```

Then you can override properties of `SectionA` using this naming convention for environment variables: `Section1__SectionA__PropA`.

Also read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#keys

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  Its been mentioned above to include this: `configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables()` in `Startup.cs`.  Is this necessary with your example?  If so where does it go?

Comment: @user1574598 No, if you use `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` it's already there.

Comment: Great, yes I have `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });` in my `Program.cs`.  Also whats the best way to debug this so I know values are being set/overriden?  Inspect the `SectionA` class maybe whist running in a container via Visual Studio?

Comment: @user1574598 You can just write `SectionA` object into log (standard output i.e. console) in place where you inject `IOptions<SectionA>`. Then just read container logs.

Comment: @user1574598 If it works for you mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Thank you, yes sorry I got sidetracked the rest of yesterday, I'll try it all today and mark your answer.  Already gave you a vote up :-)

Comment: I've managed to get the `env` vars for `appsettings` to register by injecting the `IConfiguration` into my test controller and reading the `key`; However, my original `EXAMPLE_1` implemention doesn't seem to be getting a value.  I am using Docker support in Visual Studio to spin up the container so I am using `launchsettings` to set the vars: `"environmentVariables": {
        "Section1__SectionA__PropA": "Hello PropA",
        "EXAMPLE_1": "Hello Example 1"
      }`

Comment: @user1574598 What property in what class do you want to override with `EXAMPLE_1`?

Comment: @user1574598 I'm asking because `EXAMPLE_1` doesn't follow naming convention.

Comment: Sorry, yes `EXAMPLE_1` and `EXAMPLE_2` was something I was trying to setup where I could pass `env` vars into my code directly as use as opposed to `env` vars overriding the `appsettings`.  Basically the code I started with (see above), then I thought it would be good to know how to use them to override props in `appsettings`.  Basically I would like to do both if possible.

Comment: @user1574598 Just name your variables properly and it will work out of the box.

Comment: I've added this to `startup`: `services.Configure<EnvironmentConfiguration>(Configuration);` and my `EXAMPLE_1` and `EXAMPLE_2` are working now, but I am confused as I'm passing in `Configuration`.  Both these vars are not in `appsettings` like your example.  Does this mean they are getting added at runtime dynmically?

Comment: @user1574598 it looks like you mapped `EnvironmentConfiguration` class to `appsettings` root. So it's working. Still I recommend to use specific sections in `appsettings.json` because it's "cleaner".

Comment: Ah okay, I was going to ask if there are any implications to this.  Its just experimental at the moment as I'm sick of re-building docker images just to change something like an IP etc.  In future I'll stick to the way you showed me.  I need to get more aquianted with all the configuration stuff I think.  I've marked your answer, thanks for all your help :-)

Comment: using appsetting.json is not a good idea for docker. you need to set parameters as environment variables and getSection does not work with it. you need to bind one by one.

Comment: @Farshid I just checked scenario described in my answer with docker and it works as described. Probably you're doing something wrong. Create another question and add the details.